# How to declare const char* in .cpp file

Tags: c++17

There are many questions about declaring const string in .h files, this is not my case.

I need string (for serialization purposes if it is important) to use in

My current solution is

```cpp
// file.cpp
static constexpr const char* const str = "some string key";

void MyClass::serialize()
{
    // using str
}

void MyClass::deserialize()
{
    // using str
}
```

Does it have any problems? (i.e. memory leaks, redefinitions, UB, side effects)?

P.S. is using `#define KEY "key"` could be better here (speed/memory/consistency)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned C++17, the best way to do this is with:

```cpp
constexpr std::string_view str = "some string key";
```

`str` will be substituted by the compiler to the places where it is used at compile time.

1. **Memory-wise** you got rid of storing the str in run-time since it is only available at compile time.
2. **Speed-wise** this is also marginally better because less indirections to get the data in runtime.
3. **Consistency-wise** it is also even better since `constexpr` is solely used for expressions that are immutable and available at compile time. Also `string_view` is solely used for immutable strings so you are using the exact data type needed for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, never heard about string_view before

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` implies the latter `const`, which in turn implies the `static` (for a namespace-scope variable).  Aside from that redundancy, this is fine.